# Can we identify the line number responsible for memory leaks in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm trying to find the line number causing a memory leak in an Android app. Is there a way to pinpoint the exact line?

I have tried using LeakCanary library to find the memory leaks in the Android app.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why do you post a leak trace as image when there is a link "Share link trace as text" or even a direct connection to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Hi @Robert, Thanks for the suggestions but here I was looking for the answer to the more generic question where we can find the line number causing memory leak. So I thought it was unnecessary to post the leak trace as text.

Comment: Detecting a memory leak is a complex task and there can be different reasons why a memory leak occurs. Usually you need to understand what the code is doing and what data it is required and for how long this data is required. Then compare it with the actual implementation if it accumulates somewhere references to unneeded data.

Comment: A memory leak isn’t typically caused by a line of code so much as it is caused by omitting cleanup code. You can’t really have a line number for code that your are missing.